# How do I prove this isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

Let $f(x)$ be any injective function, and let $f^n$ denote $f$ composed of itself $n$ times, such that $f^1=f(x)$, $f^2=f(f(x))$, $f^3=f(f(f(x)))$ and so on. Let $f^{-n}$ denote the inverse of $f$ composed of itself n times, such that $f^{-1}=f^{-1}(x)$, $f^{-2}=f^{-1}(f^{- 1}(x))$, $f^{-3}=f^{-1}(f^{-1}(f^{- 1}(x)))$, and so on. Let $f^0$ denote the identity function.

How can I prove that the group of all $f^n$ under composition is isomorphic to the integers under addition? I can see with the above notation that if you compose any of the functions you can just add their superscripts and you'll get the function that they reduce to. Is this enough for a proof?

Comment: Give the map $\phi (f^n ) = n $ a try. To start you can note it is a homomorphism, $ \phi (f^n \circ f^m ) = \phi ( f^{n+m} ) = n + m = \phi (f^n) + \phi(f^m)$

Comment: Hint: prove that the mapping $T:f^k \to k$ is isomorphic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. First of all, your $f\colon A\to A$ better be bijective and not just injective. And more importantly, depending on what $f$ actually is, it may be the case that $f^m$ is the identity for some $m\ne 0$. In that case, the group of all $f^n$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, but rather to $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ (if $m$ is the smallest positive integer with $f^m=\operatorname{id}$). In other words: The map $\mathbb Z\to \{\,f^n\mid n\in \mathbb Z\,\}$, $n\mapsto f^n$ is a group epimorhism, but may have nontrivial kernel.

Answer (score 3):

Counterexamples: if $f$ is the identity function, then your group is the trivial group. If $f(x) = -x$, then your group is the group with two elements.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already indicated, you need more information ( either about the set where $f$ is defined, or about $f,$ or both) before you have any chance to prove what you hope to. The only time you can be sure that an injective map $f :S \to S$ is a bijection is if $S$ is a finite set. But if $S$ is a finite set, then $f^{n}$ is the identity mapping for some finite integer $n >0,$ so in that case, as has already been noted, the desired isomorphism can't hold.